# How can I use a manually built Angular package as a node modules package in a project?

Tags: angular

I need to use the output of a manually built package as a package in an Angular project instead of the one that comes with npm install.

I tried to achieve this, by copying the manually built package and replacing the original package in node modules with it, but it doesn't work.

This is the package I used : https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/

I did : `npm install` and `npm run lib:compile:prod`

Would one of you know how to correctly use such a manually built package in a project?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to make a component as a library and use it from local path

- `ng new test-shared --createApplication=false`
- cd test-shared/
- `ng generate library test-component` -- now add your functionality to test component
- // add script to package.json
  "buildtest": "ng build test-component"
- `npm run buildtest`
- cd dist/test-component/
- `npm pack`  -it will create a .tgz whose reference we can add to any application

Now your main application where you want to use library

- // add tgz file path to our apps package.json
  "test-component": "file: ../../../../../dist/test-component/test-component-0.0.1.tgz"
- `run npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You could give it a new version number and deploy it to a local npm registry like [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio). Change your Angular `package.json` to use the new version and point npm to your local Verdaccio registry using a `.npmrc` file in the root of your Angular project.